# 'charmap' codec can't encode character but the mentionned character isn't in the input file

Tags: python, hex, decode, ebcdic

I'm trying to decode an EBCDIC file with the following Python code :

```
from os import path
import ebcdic

VERSION_EBCDIC = "cp1147"

def decodeEbcdic(inputDir, outputDir):

    for root, subdirectories, files in walk(inputDir):

        for subdirectory in subdirectories:

            #do nothing

        for file in files:
            print(file)

            f = open(path.join(root, file),'rb')
            inputData = f.read()
            f.close()

            outputData = inputData.decode(VERSION_EBCDIC)

            f = open(path.join(outputDir, file),'w')
            f.write(outputData)
            f.close()

decodeEbcdic(INPUT_DIR_EBCDIC, OUTPUT_DIR_ASCII)
```

I get the following error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8e' in position 9: character maps to <undefined>`.

But, watching the input file with HxD I can't see the mentionned byte:
[hexadecimal description of the begginning of the input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W10LO.png)

In fact, the byte 8E doesn't appear in the whole input file. nor does the byte E8.

But maybe I don't understand correctly the error message.

Comment: If it's at the start of the file then it's likely part of a byte-order mark (BOM) and does not usually appear when looking at the file in a text editor.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal bytestring that reproduces the problem please?

Comment: Sure: C4 C5 C2 E4 E3 40 C1 D3 C7 0A (it works without the last byte 0A). The editor HxD is in little endian.

Comment: I tried decoding using the ebcdic package from pypi, the bytes decode as `'DEBUT ALG\x8e'`.  You're getting the `UnicodeEncodeError` when you write to the file, because your local encoding doesn't have a mapping for `b'\x8e'`

Comment: OK. It's the package I'm using as well. Do you see this '\x8e' written somewhere or have you found a way to see what goes on the problematic byte (or something else) ?

Comment: EBCDIC files should not have 0x0A bytes as newline character. The newline character is 0x15 in EBCDIC. How was that file created?

Comment: `bytes.fromhex('C4 C5 C2 E4 E3 40 C1 D3 C7 0A').decode('cp1147')` -> `'DEBUT ALG\x8e'`. `b'\x0a'` in EBCDIC maps to Unicode codepoint `U+008E SINGLE SHIFT TWO`.

Comment: This file was created in GCOS and FTP-transfered in binary mode.

Comment: @mcoulont I don't know GCOS, but I would check with GCOS people about the purpose of that (unusual) 0x0A in the data. From "Character Data Representation Architecture" (https://www.ibm.com/downloads/cas/G01BQVRV  : *RPT - Repeat (Hex 0A) A mode control character that sets a mode of operation such as managing a printer buffer to allow a device to print repeatedly the character string contained in that buffer.* If this is really the purpose of that 0x0A, then it is an indicator to do something, and shall not be converted

Comment: They seem to use this as a line break. Strange... Thank you.

Comment: Can't you convince them to do it right, i.e. use 0x15? This is the correct value for newline character in EBCDIC.

Comment: If 0x15 would be used instead of 0x0A, you could FTP in text mode and let FTP do the conversion.

Comment: Yes, except that the EBCDIC is 1147 (not the default one). Your solutiion was the initial one and there are encoding problems.

Comment: @phunsoft: I don't think I can and, as the project is a migration, it doesn't have much sense to make things right now in the future old system.

Comment: How about looping over `inputData` first, changing all 0x0A to 0x15, before doing the `inputData.decode(VERSION_EBCDIC)`?

Comment: Yes, it's what I'm to do